# Reading from a file into 2D array returns wrong values in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fopen

so I have this simple program which reads values from a file and then I just want to print them to the screen. The problem occurs when array is printed to the screen. It adds some random numbers in the middle of the array. Does anybody have an idea what's the problem?

Here is the output:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXROW 10
#define MAXCOL 12

int main(void) {
    int i,j;

    char numbers[MAXROW][MAXCOL];


    FILE *file;  /*  FILE pointer  */
    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");  /* open a text file for reading */


    for(i=0;i<MAXROW;i++){
      for(j=0;j<MAXCOL;j++){
          fscanf(file, "%d\t", &numbers[i][j]);
          if(numbers[i][j] == '\n')
                i++;
          }
    }

    for (i=0; i<MAXROW; i++) {
      printf("\n");
        for (j=0; j<MAXCOL; j++) {
            printf("%d ",  numbers[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my data.txt file:
[image]

Comment: Please cut and paste text. Not pictures

Comment: Remove the `\t` in the `fscanf` format string. The `%d` format automatically skips leading whitespace, but you demand the `\t` be satisfied. And what is that strange `if(numbers[i][j] == '\n') i++` for? Did you mean `break;`? Why should there not be random numbers when  you break the inner loop? `char numbers[MAXROW][MAXCOL];` is *uninitialised*.

Comment: Try changing `char` to `int` in `char numbers[...][...];` -- if that works, I have an answer. If not, I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to

```
for(i=0;i<MAXROW;i++)
  for(j=0;j<MAXCOL;j++)
      fscanf(file, "%d%*c", &numbers[i][j]);
```

**numbers[i][j]** will never get the value of **'\n'** since it only matches integers when you use **%d**

Answer (score 0):

Instead use fgets() to get one line at a time, 
and then use sscanf() to get every integer on that line.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I doubt if you are hitting this condition  if(numbers[i][j] == '\n').
So, you are looping to max values & storing junk values.
read line by line & parse it  for individual numbers.